# PhpStorm external tools before commit

Tags: php, git, phpstorm

I have an External Tools entry `php-cs-fixer` and I want run it **before** commit. I found only **after**, but why after? I need before.

I want after work with file, commit it and don't worry about code style, I want to know that my PhpStorm run external tools `php-cs-fixer` before committed file.

[image]

How to add run external tools before commit ?

Comment: Why don't you use `pre-commit` git hook https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: I want doing this process with help PhpStorm

Comment: Sure, but than I don't know how I can help you.

Comment: ok, how to add to git hooks, php-sc-fixer ?

Comment: just look in the manual: you should put it in a file inside your git folder

Comment: yes, I create file `https://pastebin.com/VJuqYRHb` and call it `sudo gedit .git/hooks/pre-commit` then compare when I running `php-cs-fixer` for some file, then checkout changes and just add empty line for this file and commit it, pre-commit not worhing, only what I have in my repo in ,y commit - empty line, without php-cs-fixer working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such built-in functionality.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-111943 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notification on any progress.

---

In addition to `pre-commit` git hooks .. you may try using File Watcher functionality so it automatically runs every time you save the file (some people are using such approach).

- General info on File Watchers: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/File+Watchers+in+PhpStorm
- [PHP CS Fixer File Watcher causes File Cache Conflict in PHPStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44073562/783119) (example usage)

Answer (score 0):

Checking PHP Coding Standards before commit

`package.json`

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "pre-commit": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "check-cs": "php ./vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --config=.php-cs-fixer.dist.php -v --dry-run --stop-on-violation --using-cache=no",
    "fix-cs": "php ./vendor/bin/php-cs-fixer fix --config=.php-cs-fixer.dist.php -v --using-cache=no && exit 0"
  },
  "pre-commit": [
    "check-cs"
  ]
}
```

Install Node.js and npm

- For Ubuntu

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs npm
```

- For Windows

```bash
npm install -g npm
```

Check the installed version

```bash
node -v
npm -v
```

`Output:`

```
v12.22.9
8.5.1
```

Install a package

```bash
npm install
```

[image]